# Why do my functions under _onCameraMove run so poorly?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I pass latlnglastPosition to my widget, it's fine. I can see latitude and longitude and the value changes with zero lag as my camera position changes. However, using anything more than that causes crazy lag. It's practically unusable. Does anybody know what's causing this or if there's a better way of doing this? I'm trying to display latitude, longitude, altitude, distance from center versus current position in meters and miles. Here's the code:

```
  void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition cameraPosition) async {

    Position position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    lat = position.latitude;
    lng = position.longitude;
    alt = position.altitude;
    _distancebetween = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        _lastMapPosition.latitude, _lastMapPosition.longitude, lat, lng);
    distancebetweenFinal = _distancebetween.toStringAsFixed(2);
    distancebetweenFinalMiles = _distancebetween * (0.000621371);
    
    _lastMapPosition = cameraPosition.target;
    var latlnglastPosition = _lastMapPosition;
    _currentZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;
    
    setState(() {
      latlnglastPosition;
      distancebetweenFinal;
      distancebetweenFinalMiles;
      _distancebetween;
      _lastMapPosition;

    });
  }
```

This is using Flutter Google Maps.

Edit: I removed the conversion from meters to miles. It didn't help. I don't think the altitude is having any impact. It's just going from current camera view position to my current position that's delaying everything. Is there perhaps a way to increase the frequency i receive location info? maybe that's hanging things up.... ?

Edit: or maybe I can use get last known position when a new location is not available? Not sure if that's the best way to handle this

Edit: I set lat = 34.0; lng = 34.0; and it's super fast now. However, it doesn't solve my problem. I need lat and lng to reflect my current position, and it seems i'm either restricted in pulling my current position or it's too costly to pull it as frequently as I need to. I don't know the best way to handle this... Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that the mathematical calculations are the bottleneck.  Is constructing `Geolocator` expensive?  What about .`getCurrentPosition`?  What about `.distanceBetween`? (They are likely to be expensive given that they are asynchronous.) I would consider throttling your requests so that you update only once or twice per second.

Comment: I set     lat = 34.0;
    lng = 34.0; and it's super fast now... So, getting position.latitude; and position.longitude; from Geolocator is costly... Do you know any way I can reduce the cost of these ? Maybe if I can limit their queries to x amount per second. Not sure how to do this or if there's a better way.

Comment: I think I got it... adding to this now. If you know a better way, please let me know.

Comment: You probably don't need to construct `Geolocator` multiple times and on every call (athough I doubt that matters much.  You can easily throttle calls by comparing the current time to the time of your last call.  If it's too short, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it (I think):

I replaced

```
 Position position = await Geolocator()
     .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

with:

```
Position position = await Geolocator().getLastKnownPosition();
```

I think position.latitude and position.longitude were too costly before. So, I'm getting the last known position. If anyone knows a better way, please let me know.